# how to remove all the small islands from the Census Shapefile (zip code level)?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-sf, census

I have downloaded the Census shapefile at the zip code level, `cb_2017_us_zcta510_500k.shp` (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html)

I also have downloaded the mapping file that allows me to add the corresponding `STATE` variable (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/zcta_rel_download.html)

I merged the two and I get:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

big_df 

Simple feature collection with 44434 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -176.6847 ymin: -14.37374 xmax: 145.8304 ymax: 71.34122
epsg (SRID):    4269
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
First 10 features:
   ZCTA5CE10 STATE                       geometry
1      35442     1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.25262 3...
2      35442     1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.25262 3...
3      35442     1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.25262 3...
```

Now, I tried to filter all the small islands and Alaska:

```
remove_list <-  c("02", "15", "72", "66", "78", "60", "69",
"64", "68", "70", "74", "81", "84", "86", "87", "89", "71", "76",
"95", "79")



big_df %>% filter(!STATE %in% map(remove_list, as.integer)) %>% 
  tm_shape(.) + tm_polygons('pt_count',palette = "Reds", 
                            style = "quantile", n = 10, 
                            title = "counts")
```

but I still get some tiny islands.

[image]

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: You could use `mapedit::editMap(x = mapview::mapview(st_bbox(big_df)))` to draw a box or polygon around mainland US and do a `st_crop` or `st_intersection` with that I suppose.

Comment: very interesting... do you mind posting a working solution then? would be happy to accept that. thanks!!

Comment: It won't be reproducible as it involves drawing features by hand... Therefore, I think it is not really appropriate for an answer.

Comment: perhaps is there a way to use `sf` and say, OK now drop everything that is surrounded by water?

Comment: How would you know what is surrounded by water and what not? And what about islands on lakes?

Comment: perhaps whether there is a big number of polygons within a short radius would quality as inland. otherwise island.

Comment: That's assuming every feature is a single POLYGON, but you have MULTIPOLYGON features afaics

Comment: What counts as a 'small island', Staten Island in NY, Channel Islands in CA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way of obtaining the geometry (country outline) for mainland US:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

us = getData('GADM', country='USA', level=0) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(area = st_area(.)) %>%
  arrange(desc(area)) %>%
  slice(1) # mainland US should be the largest
```

You can then use this to run `st_intersection(big_df, us)` to extract only the parts of `big_df` within `us`. Note that it may pay off to first create a `st_buffer` or `st_convex_hull` around `us` to ensure your `big_df` doesn't get clipped somewhere along its borders.

Comment: amazing! for the sake of completeness can you try to make it work with the example data? the links are the official census ones, pretty straightforward... that will be super useful!!!

Comment: What is missing to make it work with the example data? Is `st_intersection(big_df, us)` not enough?

Comment: its up to you my friend. but posting the output (final plot) would be great! i think people looking for canonical answers like that. if thats too difficult let me know. thanks fkr helping again!!

Comment: I'm happy to provide a complete solution if you update your question to make it reproducible in the sense that the data is retrieved automatically via e.g. `tidycensus` or via `download.file` to a `tempfile()` or similar. Also the merging of the data is not reproducible.

Comment: yes you are correct. let me update that asap. thanks for pointing that out