# how to keep continental U.S.A. from shapefile at the zip code level?

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

I have downloaded the large `.shapefile` at the `zip code` level from Census.

The link is here : cb_2017_us_zcta510_500k.shp (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER_RD18/LAYER/ZCTA520/)
The problem is that reading into `geopandas` shows that, obviously, it includes alaska and all the small island around.

[image]

```
gg.head(1)
Out[709]: 
  ZCTA5CE20 GEOID20 CLASSFP20 MTFCC20 FUNCSTAT20    ALAND20  \
0     35592   35592        B5   G6350          S  298552385   

   AWATER20   INTPTLAT20    INTPTLON20  \
0    235989  +33.7427261  -088.0973903   

                                                                                                                                                                                                  geometry  
0  POLYGON ((-88.24735 33.65390, -88.24713 33.65415, -88.24656 33.65454, -88.24658 33.65479, -88.24672 33.65497, -88.24672 33.65520, -88.24626 33.65559, -88.24601 33.65591, -88.24601 33.65630, -88.24...
```

I know there is an easy solution in R (that uses the area of a polygon, see [how to remove all the small islands from the Census Shapefile (zip code level)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375619/how-to-remove-all-the-small-islands-from-the-census-shapefile-zip-code-level)) but what can I do here in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use `shapely` library in python for remove small object. Your code looks like : `import geopandas as gpd from shapely.geometry`  `import Polygon, MultiPolygon`  # Load the shapefile into a GeoDataFrame `gdf = gpd.read_file("cb_2017_us_zcta510_500k.shp")`  # Define the area threshold (in square meters) `area_threshold = 1000`  # for example  # Filter out the polygons with an area less than the threshold `gdf = gdf[gdf.geometry.area > area_threshold]`

Comment: thanks but does not seem to work on my side. can you try with the data above? I imagine this removes small zip areas, whereas I want to keep continental america and remove islands

Comment: You can remove islands by matching zipcodes using `crs` method. code : `import geopandas as gpd`

# Load the zip code level shapefile
`zip_codes = gpd.read_file("cb_2017_us_zcta510_500k.shp")`

# Load a shapefile of mainland America
`mainland = gpd.read_file("path/to/mainland_america_shapefile.shp")`

# Make sure the CRS is the same for both datasets
`zip_codes = zip_codes.to_crs(mainland.crs)`

# Do a spatial join to get only the zip codes that intersect with mainland America
`zip_codes_in_mainland = gpd.sjoin(zip_codes, mainland, how="inner", op='intersects')`

Comment: perfect, but do you know where I can find a shapefile of mainland america?

Comment: I think this is a link `https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2021&layergroup=States+%28and+equivalent%29`

Comment: Normally, the correct way to filter a GIS layer like a shapefile with its associated dbf file is by selecting attributes. But I cannot say more because I have no ideas about what your shapefile represents. Specifically what are ZCTA5CE20 GEOID20 and following fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can certainly be done using a CONUS shape definition file; however, the continental US has the convenient property of falling within a bounding box (and all non-CONUS geographies fall out of it). So the easiest way would be to filter using a bounding box:

```py
# generous bounding box
x1, y1, x2, y2 = (-130, 20, -50, 50)

gg_wgs84 = gg.to_crs('epsg:4326')
gg_conus = gg[
    (gg_wgs84.centroid.x > x1)
    & (gg_wgs84.centroid.y > y1)
    & (gg_wgs84.centroid.x < x2)
    & (gg_wgs84.centroid.y < y2)
]
```